# Quick help on bash script to remove lines of a big file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I need to remove lines from a file while contents on lines are tab delimited.
- I need to first split the line using tab, then compute the length of the 3rd segment.
- If the length is greater than say 1000, i will remove that line from the file.

I want to use sed and awk, but it's hard to get a quick start. Anyone can help? :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? awk is the obvious choice when reading space/tab/whatever-delimited text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
awk '{p = split($0,a,"\t"); if (length(a[3]) < 1000) print $0}' test.txt > out.txt
```

or
    awk -F '\t' '{if (length($3) < 1000) print $0}' test.txt > out.txt

Comment: No need for `split()` - AWK does the first one for free. See shellter's answer. Also, you're using `>`, but your question says you want to throw away long lines.

Comment: glad you're getting up-to-speed on awk. You can accept your own answer after 6 hrs to gain more reputation points. The point of my code and Dennis's comment is that when you use `-F"\t"` and `$3`, that is essentially the same as `split($0,a,"\t");print a[3]`. So either way is good, but you'll see that using numbered values for each field, ie, `$1, $2, $3, ..., $99 ...` is a key feature of awk and reduces the amount of code you have to write. AND as we all know, less code means fewer opportunities for errors to be introduced:-)! Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Thanks a lot for the good tips :) yeah, using field separator is a much better solution. i will update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F"\t" 'length($3) < 1001{print}' file > outFile
```

`-F"\t"` says split lines o tab, then print lines where the size (length) of the 3rd field is less than 1001.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You meant the length of the 3rd field. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, shellter!! :) I figured out the answer, using split function of awk. Wow, awk is so powerful! :) Thanks for your help again :)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar yes, exactly, I'll edit that. nanshi : glad this helped, yes, awk is amazingly simple yet powerful. Why do you need split? Is the 3rd field have a different separator? (A trick that I have used:-) Good you're figuring stuff out. Be sure to read awk tutorial at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Good luck to all.